# My custom main screen with the same behaviour than the Home screen

Tags: android, customization, homescreen

The main screen of my program has a number of icons that I set dynamically, due to that number can be different according to some parameters that I have in my database. To achive that, I use a gridview and it works perfectly.

But now, I need to change this main screen to behave as the home screen, I mean: I want to be able to drag and drop the icons to everywhere in the screen and also I need to be able to set my custom widget. The only thing I don't need is the flinging gesture.

Any idea how to start?

I tried to take a look to this sample (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/src/com/example/android/home/index.html) but I couldnt get how it works.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you just want the drag and drop function or do you need anything else of the 'home-screen-functions'? Because I do not think you want to create a fully home screen, but a normal app. So I would recommend to programm this yourself.

Comment: I want the drag and drop and the widget function. Maybe I didnt explain myself. I know that the home screen is divided in cells. When you set an icon, that icon fills one cell, and if you set a widget, that can fills two or more cells. That is what I want to achieve in my main screen. I know the theory but I dont kow the best way to implement this because, in my case, my icon is not just and icon (drawable), it's a custom cell from a gridview with a textview, an imageview and a shape.